# Docker selenium: Chrome timeout in headless mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, dockerfile, google-chrome-headless

I am running selenium inside docker and getting this error on this call: `driver.get(URL)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esdm.py", line 244, in <module>
    upload_to_esdm(browser, version_url, args.im_file, args.build, args.user_name, args.password, args.apps_file)
  File "esdm.py", line 78, in upload_to_esdm
    browser.get(version_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

This is my code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8196')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(URL)
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip  chromium-chromedriver
# set display port to avoid a crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

RUN pip3 install selenium
ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

This works properly in windows, but when running in docker it doesn't

Comment: Did you try without `headless` mode to ensure this is the problem? Are you sure you can access your application (or AUT) from inside of your docker container? Try to get inside of your container and ping the URL that your WebDriver needs to access. You may have to set a DNS config into your docker container.